# Specify gem installation directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have some trouble here. I am working with a Rails 2.3 project (working on the production server through ssh - don't ask why).  Here is the [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/5418493). When delayed_jobs is trying to start, the output says I need to install the bundler gem. The problem is that the gemdir is /var/lib/gems/1.8/ and I don't have the write priviliges for that directory. However there is a directory under ~/projects/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems where I can write.

How can I define the installation path for a gem?

Comment: not sure what you want, but if i understood question correctly, you can do bundle install --path your_path_here

Comment: The problem is to install the bundler itself. It's required for the app to work, but is not installed somehow.

Comment: oh i see, ill let you know if i find some way

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add the following to your **config.ru** file:

```
ENV['GEM_HOME']="#{ENV['HOME']}/projects/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems"
ENV['GEM_PATH']="#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}:/var/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
```

This will tell your rack app where to look for gems.

Also configure your server **.bashrc**:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/projects/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems"
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME:/var/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
```

Comment: config.ru is a rack configuration file in your app

Comment: I don't have one. I don't have an app either. I'm trying to install someone else's tool in Ruby, and it requires certain gems. I'm uncomfortable with having to `sudo` `gem install`, and that's why I'm here looking for a way to fine-tune the gem path. Your answer doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 46):

To install **foo** gem to a specified folder, just use `--install-dir` option, i.e.

```
$ gem install --install-dir /path/to/gems/folder foo
```

It helps when:

- one cannot use `bundle install` - e.g. if one wants to install **bundle** gem itself, or wants to install a gem (which is not listed in Gemfile) into the **bundle** folder
- `sudo gem install` command fails due to lack of write-permissions for a default installation path

Hope that helps.

Comment: This will install to a folder `/gems` with the above path

Comment: With gem version `3.3.5` I had to use `--install-dir` **and** `--no-user-install` options otherwise I got an error: _ERROR:  Use --install-dir or --user-install but not both_

Comment: I'm getting:
 
 'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EROFS)
 Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir'

Any idea?

Answer (score 19):

The environment variable `GEM_HOME` defines the gem installation location. You need to set it to desired location. The command is OS specific.

In Windows it is `set`

```
set GEM_HOME=[path]/projects/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems
```

Linux would be `export`

```
export GEM_HOME=~/projects/shared/gems/ruby/1.8/gems
```

Comment: Did that and got gem install to succeed. But the gem list command still does not show it installed, and when I try to use the bundle command it sais I need to install the gem. 
rvm gempath output features the shared gems path correctly.

Comment: @Almaron try running 'gem install bundler' to install bundler gem in that location and enable usage of 'bundle' commands

Comment: I ran 'gem install bundler' and it said that gem was intalled successfully. But when I try running 'gem list' it does not show the gem installed. Also the bundle command is not working.

Answer (score 6):

bundler accepts a --path option.

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```