# Ruby on Rails Bundler: install gems in different paths specified by Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, gemfile

Is there a way to specify in the Gemfile where each gem should be installed? The expected result would be later if I type in my Rails application directory:

> `bundle install`

then according to the Gemfile, some gems will by default be installed into system-default gempath or the path specified in previous --path option, while some other gems will be downloaded and installed into the path specified using Gemfile.

How may I do this by Gemfile?
Or maybe using .bundle/config? Any ideas?

***Using --path option of bundle is not a solution because it will enforce all gems installed into that same directory. For example, if I have dependencies on 4 gems: A, B, C, and D. I would like to run bundle command then, automatically, A and C are installed into the default dir while B and D are installed into a customized one.***

Also using the following line in a Gemfile is not a solution:

> `gem 'rspec', :path => 'some/path'`

because this requires users manually download that Gem and put it into the specified path beforehand, but I would like the Gem automatically downloaded and installed into that path. Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` but you need to remove `path` options from Gemfile

Comment: no that will enforce all gems installed into the same dir

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the bundler gem really follows your advise and installs everything to the in `--path=/your/path` specified path. So normally there should be no problem as long as you use

```
$ bundle install --path=/your/path
```

Anyway if you want to prevent bundler to install something globally even if you didn't set the `--path` flag, you can set a global `gem` prefix. 
With the `--user` flag every gem will be installed to your home directory. Just add `gem: --user-install` to your .gemrc

```
$ echo "gem: --user-install" > ~/.gemrc
```

Be aware that this rule is also used if you install a gem manually with

```
$ gem install my_awesome_gem
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. However, this won't actually solve the problem. As said, bundle install --path=/your/path will enforce all gems installed into the same directory, while I would like to run bundle command then automatically some gems installed into default system dir and some gems installed into the customized one.

Comment: I think that this will be pretty hard to accomplish with Bundler. As far as I know Bundler doesn't provide such a feature. Even if you install the system gems manually, Bundler normally disables the feature to share gems if you set the `--path`, because the whole idea of Bundler is to create an enclosed environment to develop your application. Anyway you could try to disable that behavior by digging into the `.bundle/config` file in your application and enable gem sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your gem installation directory in  **config.ru**  file

Refer this answer: [Specify gem installation directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098757/specify-gem-installation-directory)