# Installing gems for a JRuby instance which runs in cron

Tags: ruby, cron, rubygems, jruby

## Problem

My goal is to install a gem for a JRuby script that is running in cron. That gem is `typhoeus`.

## Information

Here is the output of `env`, running from cron:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
JRUBY_HOME=/home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/user
OLDPWD=/home/user
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Running `$JRUBY_HOME/bin/jruby -S gem environment` yields the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-04-12 patchlevel 330) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.6
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/user/.gem/jruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

## What I've Tried

### Changing `GEM_HOME` to match cron's jruby

In view of the output of the above `gem environment` and [another SO post about specifying gem install directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16098984/1258020),

1. I temporarily changed `$GEM_HOME` to the directory I have access to as this user (`/home/user/.gem/jruby/1.8`).
2. I ran `/home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin/jruby -S gem install typhoeus`.
3. I check for typhoeus using `/home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin/jruby -S gem list` and I *do see* `typhoeus` in the output
4. I run the same command from cron and *do not* see `typhoeus` in its output that I save to a file

### Running jruby's `gem install` *from cron*

Hacky, I know. I run exactly `/home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin/jruby -S gem install typhoeus --verbose` from inside cron and get the following dumped to a file:

```
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Installing gem ffi-1.9.8-java
```

But still, running `/home/user/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/bin/jruby -S gem install list` from cron does not show typhoeus. (And of course, the script that I'm trying to get working barfs on the library not being there).

Comment: Have you tried using bundler? It specifically manages gem load paths for you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that attempting to install `typhoeus` with this version of jruby [results in a jruby bug in versions earlier than 1.6.2](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5581).

I only witnessed by redirecting stderr  to an ouput file in cron when running `gem install typhoeus` from the crontab. (I had previously only redirected stdout).